# Report time at whole hours by prompting mini-buffer

Tags: minibuffer

Reference to [31.10.6 Appointments of Emacs Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/emacs.html#Appointments)

It provides a handy solution to report hour and remind appointments:

> For example, suppose the diary file contains these lines:
>   =M-x appt-add= adds entries to the appointment list without affecting your diary file. You delete entries from the appointment list with =M-x
>   appt-delete=.

Then if set the minutes to warning as 0 minutes to remind whole hours, it becomes a alarm to report whole hour to prompt a mini-buffer.

For example, `M-x appt-add` a whole hour "9:00pm" and set the warning as 0 minute. When it comes to 9:00pm, a mini-buffer would be prompt to report the current time.
At this moment, appointment transforms itself as an alarm to report whole hours.

Unfortunately, the appointment is one-off and it's cumbersome to set alarms manually every day.

How could have an alarm to report whole hours using appointments or any alternative solutions?

Comment: So is your question: "How do I set an alarm in emacs?" Or is it: "How do I get emacs to make an announcement every hour on the hour?"

Comment: @NickD "How do I get emacs to make an announcement every hour on hour?

Comment: Have you looked at [timers](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Timers.html#Timers)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using [timers](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Timers.html#Timers). Define a function to print out the time in the echo area:

```
(defun announce-time ()
  (message (format "The time is %s" (format-time-string "%H:%M" (current-time)))))
```

and set up a timer to run it at some initial time and every hour thereafter:

```
(run-at-time "00:00" 3600 #'announce-time)
```

You can cancel the timer if you don't want it any longer with `M-x list-timers RET` and pressing `c` on this timer.